# Getting an error as Unparseable date: " " while using formatter.parse()

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, datetime-parsing

I am taking the date as input from JSP and then I need to store in the database using hibernate.
my date format is also correct but still, it's not working.
Here is my code:

```
String dateStr =  request.getParameter("receive_date");
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy");
Date date = (Date)formatter.parse(dateStr);
System.out.println(date);     

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(date);

String formatedDate = cal.get(Calendar.DATE) + "/"+ (cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) + "/" +   cal.get(Calendar.YEAR); 
out.println("formatedDate : " + formatedDate);
```

Comment: Please provide your inputs and expected outputs.

Comment: It looks like `request.getParameter()` is getting a blank string from the request. Could this be so? You may want to use your debugger or print the string so you can check.

Comment: It doesn’t answer your question, but I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 0):

Try changing these two lines

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy");
Date date = (Date)formatter.parse(dateStr);
```

to

```
 DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy");
Date date = LocalDate.parse(dateStr, formatter);
```